# Doctrine 2 QueryBuilder Left Join with subquery

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to convert this Query to the Doctrine 2 Query Builder.

```
SELECT st.id,
       serwis2.uwagi_dla_serwisu,
       serwis2.data_wyslania,
       serwis2.data_powrotu
FROM st left join
     (select * from serwis where serwis.data_powrotu is null) serwis2
on serwis2.st_id = st.id
```

In MySQL this query is exactly what I need but I don't know how I can convert it into the QueryBuilder.

Is possible to the left join over an select subquery in the QueryBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little rusty and would need to iterate over this with the actual databases, but maybe this will help get you started...  something like:

```
$qb->select('st.id', 'serwis2.uwagi_dla_serwisu', 'serwis2.data_wyslania','serwis2.data_powrotu')
    ->from('st')
    ->addSelect('(SELECT serwis.* FROM serwis WHERE serwis.powrotu IS NULL) AS serwis2')
    ->leftJoin('st.id', 'serwis2', 'WITH', 'st.id = serwis2.st_id');
```

It's probably not something you can copy or paste, but a visit to the [query builder reference](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html#_addSelect) should help.

Comment: Thank you for quick response:) but I have a problem with this.